# How to Use Shibboleth for Single Sign-On to the AWS Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

I have instyalled shibboleth-identity-provider-3.3.1.1-x64.I want to know How to Use Shibboleth 3.3.1.1-x64 for Single Sign-On(SAML SSO) to the AWS Management Console.

Please help me.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-saml.html

Comment: how to generate saml authentication response including assertion?I want to use my application as IDP which will provide me saml authentication response including assertion?How to do that?